# Get working directory on Windows Phone

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

How to get the current working directory on windows phone?

`_wgetcwd` and `GetCurrentDirectory` are not supported on windows phone.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: He said that `GetCurrentDirectory` is not supported.

Comment: I'm using `_getcwd` on Windows Desktop and now I want to port my code to Windows Phone.

Comment: @tux3: I'm not in a managed c++ project

Comment: @Bastl, alright, sorry about that then.

Comment: @Bastl I have no idea how WP works, but from what I found the FS seems to be completely locked up on WP. Apparently you're supposed to only use your local isolated storage : `auto local = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;`. Good luck.

Comment: That's somehow also not usable. I'm in a native c++ project and I think Windows::Storage is C++/CX or C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store Apps don't have the notion of a "current directory" (the OS sets it to be the install location and doesn't let you change it).

The more interesting question is what you want to do with the working directory. Ordinarily, you would use WinRT `StorageFile` APIs to read and write files, but if you want to use `CreateFile` or `fopen` then you can get the path from a WinRT `StorageFolder`:

```
void foo()
{
  using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel;
  using namespace Windows::Storage;

  auto installLocation = std::wstring(Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path->Data());
  auto dataLocation = std::wstring(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->Path->Data());
  OutputDebugString((installLocation + L"\r\n" + dataLocation).c_str());
}
```

For my test app, this prints

> d:\temp\UniversalScratch\UniversalScratch\UniversalScratch.Windows\bin\x86\Debug\AppX
>   C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Packages\257de9ed-b378-4811-98e6-226e15a3f7f0_tp1tpcm9wdwpy\LocalState

If you use `fopen` (or `fopen_s`) with a relative filename, it will be relative to your install package.

Comment: I just wanted to port my crossplatform code to windows phone